# Redirect root page to specific store (language) view

Tags: magento2, redirect, seo

We setup a Magento 2 Shop with 3 languages:
Www.domain.com/de_ch/
Www.domain.com/fr_ch/
Www.domain.com/en_ch/

Where de_ch is the default language.
The problem now is, that we get duplicate content for [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and [www.domain.com/de_ch/](http://www.domain.com/de_ch/)

How can we permanently redirect [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to [www.domain.com/de_ch/](http://www.domain.com/de_ch/) ?

Or is there another approach to omit the duplicate pages for search engines?

Thanks
Aldo